# How to set local master for Airflow SparkSubmitOperator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

It's been more challenging than expected to properly set the Spark master via Airflow's `SparkSubmitOperator` and `SparkSubmitHook`.

It seems you must set a proper Connection for `local` otherwise it defaults to yarn.

I've set `export AIRFLOW_CONN_SPARK_LOCAL=local[2]` in my shell but the final spark-submit command still is blank: `--master`. I've recreated here:

```
>>> CONN_ENV_PREFIX = 'AIRFLOW_CONN_'
>>> import os
>>> conn_id = 'spark_local'
>>> os.environ.get(CONN_ENV_PREFIX + conn_id.upper())
'local[2]'
>>> from airflow.models import Connection
>>> Connection(conn_id=conn_id, uri='local[2]')
spark_local
>>> Connection(conn_id=conn_id, uri='local[2]').host
''
>>> Connection(conn_id=conn_id, uri='local').host
''
>>> Connection(conn_id=conn_id, uri='spark://local').host
'local'
>>> Connection(conn_id=conn_id, uri='spark://local[2]').host
'2'
```

It seems like setting the url to `spark://local` partially works, but the Airflow docs are lacking here, and I'm not sure how to set the number of local cores. Any ideas?